# How to get final result by subtracting all row values of a single column of a Sql table

Tags: sql

I have a amount column in my table.

| Amount |
| --- |
| 22 |
| 16 |
| 4 |

How can I subtract in an ascending order i.e(22-16-4) based on date and get final result : **2**

Comment: What version of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.) ?

Comment: im using microsoft sql ver 18.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working query for SQL Server:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 val - SUM(val) OVER (ORDER BY val
                                  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND
                                  1 PRECEDING) sum_val
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY val DESC;
```

### Demo

Comment: Hii @Tim Biegeleisen if there is only one amount in the table it returns null. How can i return the first amount as sum_val if there are no other values ?

Comment: @VirajKawthankar Wrap the call to `SUM(...)` in `COALESCE()`, i.e. use `COALESCE(SUM(val) OVER (...), 0)` instead